# Robotjs on Electron typeString() is not working as expected

Tags: electron, robotjs

https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs/issues/472

The annoying this with this issue is that it is working for my colleague on their machine, but it isn't working for me and we're at a loss for how to debug.

**Expected Behavior**

The expectation is that when the user hits the shortcut, which is successfully registered, that the string will appear on the screen in whatever active window the user has open

```
app.on('ready', () => {
  setTrayItem();

  const ret = globalShortcut.register('Alt+Z', () => {
    robot.typeString("Hello World");
  });

  if (!ret) {
    console.log('registration failed');
  }

});
```

**Current Behavior**

Nothing happens!

**Your Environment**

```
RobotJS version: "robotjs": "^0.5.1"
Electron: "electron": "^4.0.0",
Chromium 69.0.3497.106,
Node 10.11.0,
V8 6.9.427.24
npm version: 6.4.1
Operating System: macOS 10.14.2
```

Comment: Can you try to put the `robot.typeString` into a function delayed by setTimeout like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55464204/electron-paste-value-from-clipboard/55505589#55505589)?

Comment: It is robotJS working out of the shortcut use case?

Comment: No, we've tried stripping the functionality way back and it doesn't work when I run it. Is there a way to debug typeString()?